# SWT Menu unresponsive on MAC

Tags: java, macos, menu, swt

I was trying out example of how to create Menu using SWT. I am using Eclipse on Mac. I was referring to this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/SWTMenuExample.htm). Whenever I run this example, I have two problems:

1. The Menu doesn't show up until I make it full screen.
2. The Menu buttons are unresponsive i.e when I click on Help, it doesn't show up the dropdown containing Get Help.

Do I have to make some spwcific changes while creating Menus on Mac?

Comment: This example works fine for me on Mac OS X 10.9.4

Comment: @greg-449: So does the menu bar appear even if it is not full screen? and you are also able to click on Help to see the menu?

Comment: Yes everything works - the menu bar is at top of the screen as always with the Mac.

Comment: Mine come only when I move my mouse to the top and hold it their for a fraction of secong. It doesn't even show up when the shell is not maximized. Do you know any reason why is it that wy?

Comment: Try reinstalling your OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Probably 7 years too late, but if anybody finds this I had the same problem and I simply switch to another window and switch back to the display and it worked. I don't know why it works but it did it for me and I hope it will for you as well.